# How to avoid loading activity when screen orientation change in android

Tags: android

I am getting the value from webservice. I am displaying the progress dialog in activity. I am executing in portrait mode data is already loaded. when the user changes to landscape mode my activity loads again. How do I avoid that? I used an async task class in my activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in the activity declaration at the manifest.

Comment: Hi kgiannakakis I used asynctask class  in my activity  I have given android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" still acitivity are loading

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to the manifest file. (Or landscape if that is what you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I have just put in:

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

everywhere in my Manifest file and:

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in my main.xml.

It worked great. Here is the code parts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#7fffd4">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.Addition"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <supports-screens 
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:resizeable="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
             <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />

</intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AdditionActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.addition.INSTRUCTIONS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>

My big thanks you all you guys/girls who solves problems like the above.

Balbir
```